# Splitting logging into a separate database

Tags: postgresql

In a postgresql database for a asp.net mvc website I have 3 tables (***`visits`***, ***`uservisits`***, ***`hits`***) that have update/insert query's running on them on every pageview. Rows in ***`visits`*** (for all visitors) and ***`uservisits`*** (for authenticated visitors) are updated for the duration of each visit and ***`hits`*** has a new row inserted every time.

I'm worried that the logging query's will cause unnecessary traffic. I also found this [article](http://www.revsys.com/blog/2012/may/01/three-things-you-should-never-put-your-database/)

> *"Three things you should never put in your database"* that states *"Storing your logs in a database isn't a HORRIBLE idea, but storing them in the same database as your other production data is"*

which makes me think that maybe I should split the database so that these 3 tables are separate.

I will rarely read from the logging tables but there will be heavy read operations on other tables in the database such as searching text. I'm using caching throughout but for text searches it is likely that many unique combinations of keywords will be used and therefore caching will have limited effect there. The load will be heavy so the question is would this optimisation be worth it or is it premature optimisation?